# How L={wxw^R| w, x belongs to {a,b}^+ } is a regular language

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, automata

L={wxw^R| w, x belongs to {a,b}^+ } is a regular language. In books they make it regular by converting it into the regular expression **a(a+b)^+a + b(a+b)^+b** which clearly is an expression which starts and ends with same symbol now by doing this **w=ab x=a wr=ba** will be accepted and every string which wxwr will produce will be accepted but the strings which are not in wxwr will also be accepted like w=abb x=ab wr=bbaaaaaa will also be accepted. how in world is this a regular language when we cannot construct a finite automata ?? very confused

Answer (score 2):

> but the strings which are not in wxwr will also be accepted like w=abb x=ab wr=bbaaaaaa will also be accepted.

The regular expression `a(a+b)^+a + b(a+b)^+b` does accept the string `wxw^r = (abb)(ab)(bbaaaaaa)` because it can be interpreted as the string `wxw^r = (a)(bbabbbaaaaa)(a)`. The language does not specify how you split up the symbols between `w`, `x` and `w^r` accept to force `w` and `w^r` to be reversed. For your proposed parsing we don't satisfy that condition, but for mine we do. The reason the regular expression works is because, as long as the word starts and ends with the same symbol, we can always take `w` to be the first symbol, `w^r` to be the last and `x` to be everything else. That option is open to us and we are free to take it every time.

And we can definitely make a DFA for the regular expression. An NFA is particularly easy to make.